# Performance when using dynamic imports in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dynamic-import

I'm considering using lots of [dynamic imports](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/dynamic-import-expressions-in-typescript) in my project - but I'm concerned as I suspect it might have an effect on performance.

"traditional import":

```
import { myExampleMethod } from "./MyStuff";
// myExampleMethod();
```

dynamic import:

```
import("./MyStuff").then((myStuff) => { // myStuff.myExampleMethod(); })
```

Is there a difference worth to be mention for dynamic importing compared to "traditional importing" in performance?

Comment: Why don't you test it and see?

Comment: Also see, [which is faster](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score -1):

"Traditional import" takes 0 milliseconds:

```
const past = Date.now();
import {testMethod} from "./Test"
testMethod(past);
```

and dynamic import takes around 57 milliseconds:

```
const past = Date.now();
import("./Test").then((test) => {
    test.testMethod(past);
});
```

---

The testMethod in Test.ts...

```
export const testMethod = (past: number) => {
    console.log("test, timdiff: " + (Date.now() - past));
}
```